# Multiple account-types?

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine-orm, class-table-inheritance

I'm currently using Symfony2 and doctrine. and I'm working on a "create-account" page. There will be 2 different kinds of accounts avaliable on the page, one for `normal-users`and one for `companies`.

I've got an entity (table) called `Account` this table contains the `username`, `password`and `salt`columns.

If a company logs in I want to have the company information from a `company`-table and if a `normal-user`logs in I want the information from the `user`-table.

I've been thinking about having a column named `usertype` which tells me what type it is, then if the usertype is a `company` retrieve the company-information-entity and if it's a `user`retrieve the user-information-entity (corresponding to the `id` of the account).

Is this a good way to solve this problem? or should I have 2 different tables? AccountUser and AccountCompany?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have many columns in Company table that don't exist in the User table and vice versa the best way to solve your problem is to use [class-table inheritance](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance) which will create three tables: Account, User, Company. User and Company must be subclasses of Account entity.

According to link above you should have code like this:

```
namespace MyProject\Model;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="usertype", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"user" = "User", "company" = "Company"})
 */
class Account
{
    // ...
}

/** @Entity */
class User extends Account
{
    // ...
}

/** @Entity */
class Company extends Account
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: `DiscriminatiorMaps` are the way to go.